# Magento 2 product url key saving issue

Tags: magento2, product, url

I am trying to save product url key.When i open product admin product url key is empty for some products so i am trying to place url and saving product product is saving but url key field not changing still empty all fields changes working fine only url key not working when i change some other which is alredy existing url it effecting changes any idea

Comment: check url_rewrites

Comment: there in no url for that product